# How can I run two Chrome instances with different `user-data-dir`?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to organize a communication between two Google Chrome instances with the help of a Chrome extension (background script) with different `--user-data-dir`

Example:

Run Chrome with the flags

`--user-data-dir=/tmp/foo`

`--user-data-dir=/tmp/foo2`

At least is it possible?

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem. care to share why? what's your end goal?

Comment: Not really. You'll have to use a mediator e.g. a program that's invoked via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) or a [local] web server.